# Using expected value to find a variable inside a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, random-variables

If you have $$f_{x}(x)= \begin{cases} \alpha \sqrt{x} +\beta x^{2}, &\text{if } \; 0<x<4\\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

How would you find the $\alpha$ and the $\beta$, knowing that $E{[X^2]}=\frac{48}{5}$. Granted that integral of P.D.F. equals to 1 but not sure what to get from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two equations. Using the known property of p.d.f, we have

$$
\int_0^4 \left ( \alpha \sqrt{x} +\beta x^{2} \right ) dx = 1
$$

and using the known second moment, we have

$$
\int_0^4 x^2 \left ( \alpha \sqrt{x} +\beta x^{2} \right ) dx = 48/5
$$

If you solve these two integrals, you get two linear equations involving $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Solve this system for your parameters.